# Setting text and background colors in R editor

Tags: r

I'm a new R user (running Windows 7).  I'm visually impaired, so I want to set the text and background colors in the console and editor to be easier for me to see.  I'm using the basic Rgui, and R editor for script editing (the screen reader/magnifier program I use won't read text in RStudio or RCmdr, which is why I'm using the basic GUI).  I've already set the text and background colors for the console and pager in the Rconsole file. But I can't find a way to do the same for the editor.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Relatedly, if you know of another editor (besides the default R editor) that would let me more easily set background and text colors, I'd really appreciate the info.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Would using something like Notepad++ be helpful? There's the NppToR plugin that lets you use Notepad++ as your editor. There are shortcut keys to interface with the R console. (I'm on Ubuntu, so can't check at the moment).

Comment: as Ananda said, perhaps using a text editor as your REPL is the best idea--you'll have far more control over the background, syntax highlighting, contrast, etc.--and not just through one-at-a-time settings, but in an integrated way through a language grammar (at least that's the term used by TextMate). Sublime Text 2 (about $65) is such an editor--it's runs on Windows, and has a free REPL plug-in that is "R-aware" and supports all theming, etc. that is normally available in Sublime. Here's a blog post on how to set up Sublime Text for R (http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/)

Comment: RStudio comes with a set of themes that might be helpful, and works really excellently as a development environment for R.

Comment: which screen reader are you using?  The RStudio people may be able to look into why your reader is having trouble with RStudio